# WPF TreeView item clicked

Tags: wpf, events, click, treeview

I am a problem with the event in WPF. Say I have a underlying data model and a tree view to present the data. The simplest thing I want to do is, when I click on one item, I would do something with underlying data associated with that item.

I tried using the `MouseLeftButtonDown` event of the `Textblock`, but then the sender object is just the `Textblock` itself and I cannot get access to the underlying data.

Now I also tried using the `MouseLeftButtonDown` event of the `TreeViewItem` like this:

```
<TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type TreeViewItem}">
         <EventSetter Event="MouseLeftButtonDown" Handler="itemClicked"/>
    </Style>
</TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
```

But I did not get the handler called.

So how exactly should I do this? Is there some kind of standard approach?

Comment: use SelectedItemChanged event, note that keyboard will get the event called as well

Comment: @makc Thanks for the contribution! But I don't want the handler to be called when the selected item changes, but when the user double clicks on the item.

Comment: this is not what you have described in the question, did you try MouseDoubleClick event?

Comment: @makc Although I did not try `MouseDoubleClick`, but I read the document about it, and it will be called whenever wherever the user double clicks on the control (tree view), and again the sender is then the tree view, but not the `TreeViewItem`.

Comment: yes you are right, but you forget the fact that the item you clicked/double clicked has become selected item and you can easily access it unless you changed the selector functionality in that case post your code

Comment: @makc I have successfully done what I wanted, I changed the value of the `Event` in my original post to `MouseDoubleClick`, and now it works! Not sure why `MouseLeftButtonDown` does not work, maybe it has something to do with routed event. Anyway I am not struggling about the next problem, how to get the underlying data associated with the tree view item.

Comment: You'll have to explain better you new problem...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The MouseLeftButtonDown event is a bubbling event it got handled somewhere in its route my guess Selector. 
You can use snoop to see who handled the event.
Using PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown/SelectedItemChanged or in your case MouseDoubleClick will solve the problem.

```
<TreeView>
  <TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type TreeViewItem}">
        <EventSetter Event="MouseDoubleClick"
                Handler="itemDoubleClicked"/>
    </Style>
  </TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
</TreeView>
```